# Params is nil even though log shows passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, parameters

Paramaters from Rails debugger shows

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"m2NMruoFRr6lpsuVMK9UthlY0bsJsPmf1LWce2uKaH4=",
  "signup_id"=>"5",
  ":item_name"=>["Electric drill",
  "Screwdriver set"],
  "commit"=>"Go!"}
```

But controller create method keeps making next error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass` on the `params[:item_name]
```

from controller:

```
def create
    params[:item_name].each do |item|
      item = @signup_parent.inventories.build(inventory_params)
    end
end

def inventory_params
  params.require(:inventory).permit(:signup_id, {:item_name => []})
end
```

UPDATED controller code (see commentary thread below, still not working, but hopefully getting closer)

```
def create
    params[":item_name"].each do |item|
      item = @signup_parent.inventories.build(inventory_params)
    end
end

def inventory_params
  params.permit(:signup_id, {:item_name => []})
end
```

View code snippet in case it's helpful:

```
<%= check_box_tag ":item_name[]", "#{thing}" %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :signup_id, "#{Signup.find_by_email(session[:signup_email]).id}" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `":item_name"` (with quotes and colon) param, so i guess you should use it with quotes:

```
params[":item_name"].each do |item|
...
```

And better handle how it pass from particular form.

There is also a problem with `inventory_params` - there is no `inventory` that you can require, they are all in root. So i think this:

```
params.require(:inventory).permit(:signup_id, {:item_name => []})
```

won't work. You can use normal params, or handle this on the frontend. However you can permit them without require:

```
params.permit(:signup_id, {':item_name' => []})
```

or:

```
params.permit!
```

**Update**: you should change your files to

```
<%= check_box_tag "inventory[item_name][]", "#{thing}" %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "inventory[signup_id]", "#{Signup.find_by_email(session[:signup_email]).id}" %>
```

Then params change so you could use `params.permit(:signup_id, {:item_name => []})`

Comment: Hi thanks so much! This kind of fixed the problem, but not all the way. Now I have two problems: 1) The `:signup` param for whatever reason is no longer being passed through (`{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"m2NMruoFRr6lpsuVMK9UthlY0bsJsPmf1LWce2uKaH4=", ":item_name"=>["Vacuum", "Air mattress"], "commit"=>"Go!"}`). 2) Now everything is unpermitted `Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, :item_name, commit`

Comment: To fix that you can use `params.permit!` to permit all params, but maybe you could not use strong parameters at all.

Comment: It's weird to me that there's no way of doing this without using strong params. But in either case, the `permit!` doesn't work either. For some reason, `:signup_id` refuses to be passed through.... (though everything else does). I've added the view code if it's helpful

Comment: Yes, you should properly pass parameters to action. Show me where you calls it.

Comment: Yes, but what about other.

Comment: yes if i added it it works as well, params.require(:signup_id, ":item_name")